# Why does my method that scans a file and prints out the result print 1 space further than the last time?

Tags: java, arrays, loops, java.util.scanner

I'm currently writing a quite lengthy piece of code to recreate Conway's Game of Life and have just realized that when I run my code, the method that I made to scan through a file and print itself out as matrix doesn't work as intended. I've tried messing around with it, but to no avail.

```
public static String[][] originalBoardCreation() {
        Scanner sc= MyUtils.readFile(inpFileName);
        
        width = sc.nextInt();
        height = sc.nextInt();  
        sc.nextLine();
        
        String[][] board = new String[width][height];
        String[] line = new String[board.length];
        
        while (sc.hasNext()) {
            for (int i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
                line[i] = sc.nextLine().trim();
                
                for (int j = 0; j < line.length; j++) {
                    board[i][j] = line[j];
                }
            }
        } 
        
        return board;
    }
```

When I call it to main with `System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(originalBoardCreation()));` , I get

```
[[.xxxxxxxx., null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null], [.xxxxxxxx., x.x.x.x.x., null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null], [.xxxxxxxx., x.x.x.x.x., .x.x.x.x.., null, null, null, null, null, null, null], [.xxxxxxxx., x.x.x.x.x., .x.x.x.x.., xxxxxxx..., null, null, null, null, null, null], [.xxxxxxxx., x.x.x.x.x., .x.x.x.x.., xxxxxxx..., .........., null, null, null, null, null], [.xxxxxxxx., x.x.x.x.x., .x.x.x.x.., xxxxxxx..., .........., .........., null, null, null, null], [.xxxxxxxx., x.x.x.x.x., .x.x.x.x.., xxxxxxx..., .........., .........., .........., null, null, null], [.xxxxxxxx., x.x.x.x.x., .x.x.x.x.., xxxxxxx..., .........., .........., .........., ....xxx..., null, null], [.xxxxxxxx., x.x.x.x.x., .x.x.x.x.., xxxxxxx..., .........., .........., .........., ....xxx..., .........., null], [.xxxxxxxx., x.x.x.x.x., .x.x.x.x.., xxxxxxx..., .........., .........., .........., ....xxx..., .........., ..........]]
```

I'm trying to get something like `[[., x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, .], ... etc`  , but I have no clue as to why this is happening, so it would be great if I could get a brief explanation or error in my logic, thank you!

Comment: I am not sure whether I understood your requirement correctly, but try changing ```line``` from ```String[]``` to ```String```, it might work

Comment: Can you [edit] your question and post contents of file `inpFileName`?

Comment: Or rather than a `String[] line` you might want to use a character array `Char[] line` or a single string `String line;` as suggested above and get individual characters `board[i][j] = line.charAt(j);`

Comment: You're assigning uninitialized (`null`)  values to `board[i][j]` in your inner loop. Try it out on paper: what happens when you read the first line, and you reach `i = 0` and `j = 1`. Spoiler: only `line[0]` will have a value at this point, and you're assigning `line[1]` to `board[0][1]`.

Also you're assigning a whole line to a single cell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the problem is being caused by the fact that your reading a line of text from a file in and expecting it to be *magically* split for you into a string array.

```java
public static String[][] originalBoardCreation()
{
  Scanner sc= MyUtils.readFile(inpFileName);

  width = sc.nextInt();
  height = sc.nextInt();  
  sc.nextLine();

  String[][] board = new String[width][height];

  while ( sc.hasNext() )
  {
    for ( int i = 0; i < board.length; i++ )
    {
      String line = sc.nextLine().trim();  // read the text line in
      char tiles[] = line.toCharArray();    // now split the line into an array

      for ( int j = 0; j < tiles.length; j++ )
      {
        board[i][j] = String.valueOf(tiles[j]);  // Now assign the elements to the current row on your board
      }
    }
  } 
  return board;
}
```

I haven't tested this, but something like this should work.